# How would I store data from this constructor with two data types into an array after being tokenized?

Tags: java, arrays, storage, stringtokenizer

I have this constructor class here

```
public class Car {
private String make,model;
private int year,mileage;

public String toString() {
return "Car [make=" + make + ", model=" + model +", "
        + "year =" + year + ", mileage=" + mileage + "]"; }


public String getMake() {
    return make;
}
public Car(String make, String model, int year, int mileage) {
    super();
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
    this.mileage = mileage;
}
public void setMake(String make) {
    this.make = make;
}
public String getModel() {
    return model;
}
public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}
public int getYear() {
    return year;
}
public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}
public int getMileage() {
    return mileage;
}
public void setMileage(int mileage) {
    this.mileage = mileage;
}
}
```

Now using this I'm trying to store the data into two arrays where one will be sorted using the sorting algorithm but I'm having trouble understanding how i'm supposed to store them in arrays when they're different types. I attempted to try it on my own but I think i'm not doing it right. It's supposed to read from a text file and store the make, model year and mileage but the fact that it's two data types is throwing me off.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Storing {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TextFileInput fileInput = new TextFileInput("CarDetails.txt");
    ArrayList <Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    String line = fileInput.readLine();


    while(line!=null) {
        int [] values = new int [4];

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
        int numOfCommas = st.countTokens();

        for(int i = 0;i<numOfCommas;i++) {
            values[i]=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken(","));
        }
        cars.add(new Car(values[0],values[1],values[2],values[3]));

        line = fileInput.readLine();
    }
```

Please help me get in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

`make` and `model` aren't `int`(s). Just read in a `String[]` and only parse the last two tokens. Something like,

```
while (line != null) {
    String[] values = new String[4];

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
    int numOfCommas = st.countTokens();

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfCommas; i++) {
        values[i] = st.nextToken();
    }
    cars.add(new Car(values[0], values[1], 
            Integer.parseInt(values[2]), Integer.parseInt(values[3])));

    line = fileInput.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly parse it into a different data type and back.  Generics will allow for a single data type at a time but not 2 different data types at the same time...